# Dart: Get enum from String?

Tags: json, parsing, enums, dart

Hi there I have the following class in the Google Maps dart library and want to parse a Google Style JSONs into Dart object oriented format.

Within the lib (can NOT be changed!) I have the following Enum:

```
part of google_maps.src;

@jsEnum
class MapTypeStyleElementType extends JsEnum {
  static final values = <MapTypeStyleElementType>[
    ALL,
    GEOMETRY,
    GEOMETRY_FILL,
    GEOMETRY_STROKE,
    LABELS,
    LABELS_ICON,
    LABELS_TEXT,
    LABELS_TEXT_FILL,
    LABELS_TEXT_STROKE
  ];
  static final ALL = new MapTypeStyleElementType._('all');
  static final GEOMETRY = new MapTypeStyleElementType._('geometry');
  static final GEOMETRY_FILL = new MapTypeStyleElementType._('geometry.fill');
  static final GEOMETRY_STROKE =
      new MapTypeStyleElementType._('geometry.stroke');
  static final LABELS = new MapTypeStyleElementType._('labels');
  static final LABELS_ICON = new MapTypeStyleElementType._('labels.icon');
  static final LABELS_TEXT = new MapTypeStyleElementType._('labels.text');
  static final LABELS_TEXT_FILL =
      new MapTypeStyleElementType._('labels.text.fill');
  static final LABELS_TEXT_STROKE =
      new MapTypeStyleElementType._('labels.text.stroke');
  MapTypeStyleElementType._(o) : super.created(o);
}
```

This is sample JSON of the JSON:

```
  {
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f5f5"
      }
    ]
  }
```

This is what I tried (Part of my Parser):

```
m.elementType = MapTypeStyleElementType.values[value];
```

> value is the String "**geometry**" and I want MapTypeStyleElementType.GEOMETRY back

This is the error stacktrace:

```
EXCEPTION: Invalid argument(s): geometry(anonymous function) @ VM1449:1 VM1449:1 STACKTRACE:(anonymous function) @ VM1449:1 VM1449:1
#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:153)
#1      Parser.getMapStyle.<anonymous closure> (package:xxx/map_component/mapstyle.dart:17:59)
#2      _HashVMBase&MapMixin&&_LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:348)
#3      Parser.getMapStyle (package:xxx/map_component/mapstyle.dart:15:13)
```

What I try is to simply create the adequate enum from the given string ***without making an if/else statement for every value*** (because the libs has enums with hundreds of values this really matters!). Unfortunatly *the constructor is private* how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JsEnum` extends `JsRef` which stores the String as a private variable: `_value`.

However `_value` is exposed via the function: `asJs`:

```
/// Returns the underlying js value corresponding to [o] if [o] is a [JsRef]
/// (usually [JsEnumBase] or [JsInterface]). Otherwise it returns [o].
asJs(o) => o is JsRef ? o._value : o;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the String passed into the constructor, you could create the mapping you want by iterating over the values list.

```
var elementTypes = <String, MapTypeStyleElementType>{};
for (var value in MapTypeStyleElementType.values) {
  // just guessing on the JsEnum API here...
  elementTypes[value.name] = value;
}
```

Then in your parsing code you can write

```
m.elementType = elementTypes[value];
```

Comment: Nice idea but unfortunatly it does not help because value has only the same properties/methods as Object: value.hashCode(), value.runtimeType(), value.toString() and value.noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation). Do you think I can compare using the hashcode?

Comment: Btw. JsEnum comes from `import 'package:js_wrapping/js_wrapping.dart';`

Comment: It looks like you can extract the value using the [`asJs` function](https://github.com/a14n/dart-js-wrapping/blob/master/js_wrapping/lib/js_wrapping.dart#L48).